# Google TV emulator in bridge network mode

Tags: android, google-tv

I want to connect to my app running in the emulator from another machine on my local network. The ip assigned to emulator is 10.0.2.15 while my host machine has ip 192.168.1.* . Is there any way to run the emulator in bridge mode such that it gets an ip in the range 192.168.1.* ?

Answer (score 0):

The Android Emulator has a virtual router connecting it to the network.  You can use the redir command to setup network connections.  See this article:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: Thanks simon. But what this will do is allow port forwarding from the host machine (and not the external machines). What I finally ended up with is having a ssh-tunnel to redirect all traffic on my external interface on port XYZ to localhost:XYZ, and then use redir command to forward it to my app running inside the emulator.